# How can I get food in deserts and mesas?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How can I survive if I spawned in a desert, where food is scarce? As far as I know, no animals spawn there, there are only a few rivers with grass and very sparse oak apple-bearing trees, making food gathering hard.
**What method should I use to gather food in deserts?**

Comment: Given the lack of trees and food, the best course of action is to move out of the desert if you've spawned in one.

Answer (score 2):

Make a [fishing rod](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Fishing_Rod), find a river or desert well, and [go fishing](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Fishing). All you need is a single block of wood and some string from a Spider. Note that you can fish in any body of water, including player-created ones, so you can grab a bucket and make a pond at your desert home, to fish at your convenience. This is the best way to survive on a desert island too.